# how can I get the contents of a <g:select....>

Tags: grails

I coded the following in a .gsp

```
<g:select name="partner.id" from="${org.strotmann.partner.adapter.Partner.partners}" value="${experteInstance.partnerId}" optionKey="id" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': '']"/>
```

The org.strotmann....partners List contains a list of partnerNames. I just get the key of the selected name in params in my controller.

How should I code the g:select... to get the name too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the `optionValue`:

```
<g:select name="partner.id" from="${org.strotmann.partner.adapter.Partner.partners)}" value="${experteInstance.partnerId}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': '']"/>
```

The optionValue is described [here](https://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/select.html):

> optionValue (optional) - By default the body of each  element
>   will be the result of a toString() call on each element in the from
>   attribute list. Setting this allows the value to be a bean property of
>   each element in the list.